# Community.csharpsqlite issue on Mono

Tags: c#, macos, sqlite, mono

I'm trying to connect and do a simple query on a simple sqlite database.
I made a c# project and run it on windows. Everything works well.
Same exe brought in a Mac OSX with Lion and Mono installed, will crash. Here a snippet code

```
        using (SqliteConnection connect = new SqliteConnection())
        {
            connect.ConnectionString = cs;
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("1"));
            connect.Open();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("2"));

            using (SqliteCommand command = new SqliteCommand(@"SELECT * FROM User", connect))
            {
                command.ExecuteReader();
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("3"));
            }
        }
```

The program crash before step 3, in fact I have the following exception when the ExecuteReader start.  Here the exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: Community.CsharpSqlite.SQLiteClient.SqliteSyntaxException: unable to open database file
  at Community.CsharpSqlite.SQLiteClient.SqliteCommand.GetNextStatement (System.String pzStart, System.String& pzTail, Community.CsharpSqlite.Vdbe& pStmt) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Community.CsharpSqlite.SQLiteClient.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader (CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean want_results, System.Int32& rows_affected) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Community.CsharpSqlite.SQLiteClient.SqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoConsoleSqLite.Program.LoadData () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoConsoleSqLite.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Community.CsharpSqlite.SQLiteClient.SqliteSyntaxException: unable to open database file
  at Community.CsharpSqlite.SQLiteClient.SqliteCommand.GetNextStatement (System.String pzStart, System.String& pzTail, Community.CsharpSqlite.Vdbe& pStmt) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Community.CsharpSqlite.SQLiteClient.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader (CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean want_results, System.Int32& rows_affected) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Community.CsharpSqlite.SQLiteClient.SqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoConsoleSqLite.Program.LoadData () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoConsoleSqLite.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

This is the connection string that I'm using:
   `"Data Source=/Users/User/Desktop/MonoSQL/data.sqlite;Version=3;"`

Comment: does that file really exist? `/Users/User/Desktop/MonoSQL/data.sqlite`?

Comment: have you checked the permissions of the file?

Comment: can you open it with the sqlite3 command line client?

Comment: Yes, with sqlite3 command line client works. Permissions are 777 on db file and exe folder.

Comment: that is certainly strange